# PHP - If key value of one object matches different object key value

Tags: php, arrays, object, compare

Im using WCMP for Woocommerce. On the "vendors" page, it isnt possible to use get_terms for sub/child categories. Normally in WP, get_terms outputs sub/child categories with a parent ID. Something like this

```
$sub_terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'parent' => $parent_term->term_id
]);
```

For some reason, WCMP will output ALL sub/child categories even though they're not listed in the array of objects.

The array "$all_cats" outputs this below.

As a result, i'm trying to loop through the array of objects and get the term_id & name if a term_id matches the parent value of another object

As you can see index[0] "parent" value (384) is the "term_id" value of index[2] (384). I want to get term_id & name, if one objects "term_id" value matches another objects "parent" value

I've tried this with no success. Can anyone give me some pointers where im going wrong? Please note, i'm not looking for a "Wordpress" solution, how can i do this is PHP

```
foreach ($all_cats as $cat_term) {
    $category_termID = $cat_term->term_id;
    $category_title = $cat_term->name;
    $category_slug = $cat_term->slug;
    $category_parent = $cat_term->parent;

    // Doesnt Work
    if (property_exists($cat_term->term_id, $cat_term->parent)) {
        // get term_id & name
    };
    // Doesnt Work
    if (array_key_exists($cat_term->term_id, $cat_term->parent)) {
        // get term_id & name
   }
}

Array (
[0] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 386
        [name] => Ales
        [slug] => ales
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 386
        [taxonomy] => product_cat
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 384
        [count] => 10
        [filter] => raw
    )
[1] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 385
        [name] => Beers
        [slug] => beers
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 385
        [taxonomy] => product_cat
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 384
        [count] => 10
        [filter] => raw
    )

[2] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 384
        [name] => Beers &amp; Ales
        [slug] => beers-ales
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 384
        [taxonomy] => product_cat
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 20
        [filter] => raw
    )

[3] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 403
        [name] => Red
        [slug] => red
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 403
        [taxonomy] => product_cat
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 387
        [count] => 9
        [filter] => raw
    )

[4] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 387
        [name] => Wines
        [slug] => wines
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 387
        [taxonomy] => product_cat
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 15
        [filter] => raw
    )

)
```

Comment: Whatever you actually want to do - I don't totally get your explanation - I very much doubt, that `property_exists` will have _anything_ to do with the solution. That function checks if a _class_ (or class instance) has a certain property. It does not care about what value that property might have, if any, _at all_.

Comment: Ive added more info on what i'm looking to achieve, hope this helps

Comment: `array_column` can help you extract the `parent` value from all those objects into a flat array. And then you can just use `in_array` to check if the `term_id` of the current element inside your loop, is contained in that.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, thats outputting the right data. Appreciate your help. Thanks!